# Setting css according to particular dimension

Tags: javascript, css, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using a Vue component and am completely new to this JavaScript framework. I have a problem where in I want to set padding according to page dimensions.

```
padding: 12px 50px 12px 0px;  // This is dimension at 768(Both width & height)
```

```
padding: 12px 12px 12px 0px;  // This is dimension for normal web page
```

This image is set at padding: 12px 12px 12px 0px; and page dimension is at 768(Toggle device)
[image]

What i need
[image]
In the case of the Normal dimension, everything all labels and input fields are coming horizontally.

Comment: I believe what you need is either a fixed width for labels or something like `display: grid` to get that wanted view. A padding would only help if you would apply it to each label individually which is tedious and not recommended.

Comment: As for the problem you mentioned use a media query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per your image of result, i suggest remove all element padding and put all element into main div and then set padding to main div as,

```
<div class="maindiv" style="padding:12px 12px 12px 0px">
 <!--here all element like label,para,div--->
</div>
```

Comment: What about if I set the dimension at 768? that 50px padding-right

Comment: add in css  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {   .maindiv{ padding-right:50px;  }       }